# Performance on this query

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

We have the query below in our software to get a set of results which can be used to calculate the score of a location. As it stands it is too slow to retrieve the results in the timely fashion we need. I have some ideas where there may be some improvements, but any ideas are welcome. Also if you have some advice in general, please tell me!

### Database setup

The database is setup in such a way that every poco c# object translates to two tables. One with the relationships and one that contains the details. This is important for us, since we often step back to the previous version of the details of an object. This can be seen on the research & researchdetails. To combine them I'm comparing every table to itself to match the timestamp. With the max timestamp of that equation I get the latest version.

#### The query setup

The query retrieves all the answers of filled surveys. The answers are filtered on the specific needs by using the variables. If there are left as zero, they don't need to be taken into account. Eventually all the answers that match the condition are returned and grouped.

The variables will be introduced by the SQL reader in C#. Normally they are commented out in the query itself and enabled when I need to check things manually.

### My ideas

- I think the way we combine the relation object and the details object are combined here can be improved, but I'm not sure how.
- I want to introduce views for the revisioning system and if I'm correct, because of the indexing that occurs on the views it can contribute.
- At the moment we have some basic indexing that is generated by Entity Framework Core and when we execute the query in SSMS we don't have any index suggestions, but I feel I'm still missing some.

### Create tables

```
CREATE TABLE [Survey].[Researches](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Researches] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:32:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ResearchId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SurveyGroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling_Groups_SurveyGroupId] FOREIGN KEY([SurveyGroupId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[Groups] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling_Groups_SurveyGroupId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling_Researches_ResearchId] FOREIGN KEY([ResearchId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[Researches] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling_Researches_ResearchId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[Groups]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:32:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[Groups](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [RetailFormulaId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Groups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[Groups]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Groups_RetailFormulas_RetailFormulaId] FOREIGN KEY([RetailFormulaId])
REFERENCES [Clients].[RetailFormulas] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[Groups] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Groups_RetailFormulas_RetailFormulaId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[Versions]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:32:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[Versions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ResearchType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SurveyGroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Versions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[Versions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Versions_Groups_SurveyGroupId] FOREIGN KEY([SurveyGroupId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[Groups] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[Versions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Versions_Groups_SurveyGroupId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[CompletedSurveys]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:33:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveys](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [EnteredFromIP] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MysteryShoppingResultConnectionId] [int] NULL,
    [SurveyVersionId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CompletedSurveys] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveys]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveys_MysteryShoppingResultConnections_MysteryShoppingResultConnectionId] FOREIGN KEY([MysteryShoppingResultConnectionId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[MysteryShoppingResultConnections] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveys] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveys_MysteryShoppingResultConnections_MysteryShoppingResultConnectionId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveys]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveys_Versions_SurveyVersionId] FOREIGN KEY([SurveyVersionId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[Versions] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveys] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveys_Versions_SurveyVersionId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[CompletedSurveyStatusHistory]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:33:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyStatusHistory](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompletedSurveyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PrivateComment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PublicComment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [StatusCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CompletedSurveyStatusHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyStatusHistory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyStatusHistory_CompletedSurveys_CompletedSurveyId] FOREIGN KEY([CompletedSurveyId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[CompletedSurveys] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyStatusHistory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyStatusHistory_CompletedSurveys_CompletedSurveyId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[CompletedSurveyStatusHistory]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:33:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyStatusHistory](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompletedSurveyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PrivateComment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PublicComment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [StatusCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CompletedSurveyStatusHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyStatusHistory]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyStatusHistory_CompletedSurveys_CompletedSurveyId] FOREIGN KEY([CompletedSurveyId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[CompletedSurveys] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyStatusHistory] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyStatusHistory_CompletedSurveys_CompletedSurveyId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [SurveyRevisions].[CompletedSurveyDetails]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:33:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [SurveyRevisions].[CompletedSurveyDetails](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ChangedById] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
    [InternalScore] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Score] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CompletedSurveyDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [SurveyRevisions].[CompletedSurveyDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyDetails_ApplicationUsers_ChangedById] FOREIGN KEY([ChangedById])
REFERENCES [General].[ApplicationUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE SET NULL
GO

ALTER TABLE [SurveyRevisions].[CompletedSurveyDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyDetails_ApplicationUsers_ChangedById]
GO

ALTER TABLE [SurveyRevisions].[CompletedSurveyDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyDetails_CompletedSurveys_ParentId] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[CompletedSurveys] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [SurveyRevisions].[CompletedSurveyDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyDetails_CompletedSurveys_ParentId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[DisplayTags]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:34:01 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[DisplayTags](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [RetailFormulaId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TagId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DisplayTags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[DisplayTags]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DisplayTags_RetailFormulas_RetailFormulaId] FOREIGN KEY([RetailFormulaId])
REFERENCES [Clients].[RetailFormulas] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[DisplayTags] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DisplayTags_RetailFormulas_RetailFormulaId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[DisplayTags]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DisplayTags_Tags_TagId] FOREIGN KEY([TagId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[Tags] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[DisplayTags] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DisplayTags_Tags_TagId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[DisplayTags]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:34:01 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[DisplayTags](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [RetailFormulaId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TagId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DisplayTags] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[DisplayTags]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DisplayTags_RetailFormulas_RetailFormulaId] FOREIGN KEY([RetailFormulaId])
REFERENCES [Clients].[RetailFormulas] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[DisplayTags] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DisplayTags_RetailFormulas_RetailFormulaId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[DisplayTags]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DisplayTags_Tags_TagId] FOREIGN KEY([TagId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[Tags] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[DisplayTags] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DisplayTags_Tags_TagId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:34:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompletedSurveyAnswerId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DisplayTagId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling_CompletedSurveyAnswers_CompletedSurveyAnswerId] FOREIGN KEY([CompletedSurveyAnswerId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[CompletedSurveyAnswers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling_CompletedSurveyAnswers_CompletedSurveyAnswerId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling_DisplayTags_DisplayTagId] FOREIGN KEY([DisplayTagId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[DisplayTags] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling_DisplayTags_DisplayTagId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:34:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CompletedSurveyAnswerId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DisplayTagId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling_CompletedSurveyAnswers_CompletedSurveyAnswerId] FOREIGN KEY([CompletedSurveyAnswerId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[CompletedSurveyAnswers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling_CompletedSurveyAnswers_CompletedSurveyAnswerId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling_DisplayTags_DisplayTagId] FOREIGN KEY([DisplayTagId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[DisplayTags] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling_DisplayTags_DisplayTagId]
GO
USE [secretcollect-production]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [Survey].[CompletedSurveyAnswers]    Script Date: 03/07/2017 23:34:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyAnswers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Answer] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ChoiceWeight] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CompletedSurveyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Explanation] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SurveyAnswerOptionId] [int] NULL,
    [SurveyQuestionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [int] NULL,
    [Weight] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CompletedSurveyAnswers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyAnswers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyAnswers_CompletedSurveys_CompletedSurveyId] FOREIGN KEY([CompletedSurveyId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[CompletedSurveys] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyAnswers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyAnswers_CompletedSurveys_CompletedSurveyId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyAnswers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyAnswers_QuestionAnswerOptions_SurveyAnswerOptionId] FOREIGN KEY([SurveyAnswerOptionId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[QuestionAnswerOptions] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyAnswers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyAnswers_QuestionAnswerOptions_SurveyAnswerOptionId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyAnswers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyAnswers_Questions_SurveyQuestionId] FOREIGN KEY([SurveyQuestionId])
REFERENCES [Survey].[Questions] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Survey].[CompletedSurveyAnswers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CompletedSurveyAnswers_Questions_SurveyQuestionId]
GO
```

### The query

```
DECLARE @UsableCompletedSurveyStatus INT = 30
DECLARE @ResearchId INT = 3
DECLARE @DisplayTagId INT = 0
DECLARE @VisitTypeId INT = 0
DECLARE @VisitPeriodId INT = 32
DECLARE @LocationId INT = 0
DECLARE @QuestionIdentificationTagId INT = 0

SELECT      
        t1.RetailFormulaId                                      AS  RetailFormulaId, //[Survey].MysteryShoppingResultConnections
        t1.LocationId                                           AS  LocationId, //[Survey].MysteryShoppingResultConnections
        t1.VisitPeriodId                                        AS  VisitPeriodId, //[Survey].MysteryShoppingResultConnections
        t1.VisitPeriodName                                      AS  VisitPeriodName, //[MysteryShoppingRevisions].VisitPeriodDetails
        t1.VisitPeriodStart                                     AS  VisitPeriodStart, //[MysteryShoppingRevisions].VisitPeriodDetails
        t1.CompletedSurveyId                                    AS  CompletedSurveyId,//[Survey].CompletedSurveys
        CAST(SUM(t1.QuestionSubtotal) AS FLOAT)  / SUM(t1.QuestionWeight)       
                                                                AS  Average //[Survey].CompletedSurveyAnswers   
FROM 
(
SELECT  ResultConnection.RetailFormulaId                        AS  RetailFormulaId,
        ResultConnection.LocationId                             AS  LocationId,
        ResultConnection.VisitPeriodId                          AS  VisitPeriodId,
        VisitPeriodDetails.Name                                 AS  VisitPeriodName,
        VisitPeriodDetails.[Begin]                              AS  VisitPeriodStart,
        CompletedSurvey.Id                                      AS  CompletedSurveyId,
        CompletedSurveyAnswer.SurveyQuestionId                  AS  SurveyQuestionId,
        CompletedSurveyAnswer.[Weight]                          AS  QuestionWeight,
        Avg(CompletedSurveyAnswer.Value) * CompletedSurveyAnswer.[Weight]
                                                                AS  QuestionSubtotal


    FROM        [Survey].Researches                             AS  Research
    INNER JOIN  [SurveyRevisions].ResearchDetails               AS  ResearchDetails                         ON  ResearchDetails.ParentId = Research.Id
                                                                                                            AND ResearchDetails.TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM [SurveyRevisions].ResearchDetails WHERE ParentId = Research.Id)

    -- Inner join surveygroups
    INNER JOIN  [Survey].ResearchSurveyGroupCoupling            AS  SurveyGroupCoupling                     ON  Research.Id = SurveyGroupCoupling.ResearchId
    INNER JOIN  [Survey].Groups                                 AS  SurveyGroup                             ON  SurveyGroup.Id = SurveyGroupCoupling.SurveyGroupId
    INNER JOIN  [Survey].Versions                               AS  SurveyVersion                           ON  SurveyVersion.SurveyGroupId = SurveyGroup.Id

    -- Inner join acceptedresults
    INNER JOIN  [Survey].CompletedSurveys                       AS  CompletedSurvey                         ON  CompletedSurvey.SurveyVersionId = SurveyVersion.Id
    INNER JOIN  [Survey].CompletedSurveyStatusHistory           AS  CompletedSurveyStatus                   ON  CompletedSurveyStatus.CompletedSurveyId = CompletedSurvey.Id
                                                                                                            AND CompletedSurveyStatus.TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX([TimeStamp]) FROM [Survey].CompletedSurveyStatusHistory WHERE CompletedSurveyId = CompletedSurvey.Id)
    INNER JOIN  [SurveyRevisions].CompletedSurveyDetails        AS  CompletedSurveyDetails                  ON  CompletedSurveyDetails.ParentId = CompletedSurvey.Id
                                                                                                            AND CompletedSurveyDetails.TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX([TimeStamp]) FROM [SurveyRevisions].CompletedSurveyDetails WHERE ParentId = CompletedSurvey.Id)
    INNER JOIN  [Survey].MysteryShoppingResultConnections       AS  ResultConnection                        ON  ResultConnection.Id = CompletedSurvey.MysteryShoppingResultConnectionId

    -- Join displayTags
    INNER JOIN  [Survey].DisplayTags                            AS  DisplayTag                              ON  DisplayTag.RetailFormulaId = ResultConnection.RetailFormulaId
    
    INNER JOIN  [MysteryShoppingRevisions].VisitPeriodDetails   AS  VisitPeriodDetails                      ON  VisitPeriodDetails.ParentId = ResultConnection.VisitPeriodId
                                                                                                            AND VisitPeriodDetails.TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX([TimeStamp]) FROM [MysteryShoppingRevisions].VisitPeriodDetails WHERE ParentId = ResultConnection.VisitPeriodId)
    
    INNER JOIN  [Survey].ResultAnswerDisplayTagCoupling         AS  AnswerTagCoupling                       ON  AnswerTagCoupling.DisplayTagId = DisplayTag.Id
    INNER JOIN  [Survey].CompletedSurveyAnswers                 AS  CompletedSurveyAnswer                   ON  CompletedSurveyAnswer.Id = AnswerTagCoupling.CompletedSurveyAnswerId
                                                                                                            AND CompletedSurveyAnswer.CompletedSurveyId = CompletedSurvey.Id

    INNER JOIN  [Survey].Questions                              AS  SurveyQuestion                          ON  SurveyQuestion.Id = CompletedSurveyAnswer.SurveyQuestionId

    WHERE       CompletedSurveyStatus.StatusCode = @UsableCompletedSurveyStatus
    AND         Research.Id = @ResearchId
    AND         CompletedSurveyAnswer.[Weight] > 0
    AND         CompletedSurveyAnswer.Value IS NOT NULL
    AND         (@LocationId = 0 OR ResultConnection.LocationId = @LocationId)
    AND         (@VisitTypeId = 0 OR ResultConnection.VisitTypeId = @VisitTypeId)
    AND         (@VisitPeriodId = 0 OR ResultConnection.VisitPeriodId = @VisitPeriodId)
    AND         (@DisplayTagId = 0 OR Displaytag.Id = @DisplayTagId)
    AND         (@QuestionIdentificationTagId = 0 OR SurveyQuestion.IdentifiedByDisplayTagId = @QuestionIdentificationTagId)
    AND         CompletedSurveyAnswer.TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) 
                                                                FROM        [Survey].CompletedSurveyAnswers AS  InnerAnswer
                                                                INNER JOIN  [Survey].Questions              AS  InnerQuestion   ON  InnerQuestion.Id = InnerAnswer.SurveyQuestionId
                                                                WHERE       InnerQuestion.IdentifiedByDisplayTagId = SurveyQuestion.IdentifiedByDisplayTagId
                                                                AND         InnerAnswer.CompletedSurveyId = CompletedSurvey.Id)
    
    GROUP BY    ResultConnection.RetailFormulaId, ResultConnection.LocationId, ResultConnection.VisitPeriodId, VisitPeriodDetails.Name, VisitPeriodDetails.[Begin], CompletedSurveyAnswer.SurveyQuestionId, CompletedSurveyAnswer.[Weight], CompletedSurvey.Id
) 
AS  t1

GROUP BY RetailFormulaId, LocationId, VisitPeriodId, VisitPeriodName, VisitPeriodStart, CompletedSurveyId
ORDER BY CompletedSurveyId
```

I can generate a create script for the database if needed.

**Possible solutions:**

There was a suggestion to use `ROW_NUMBER` rather than `MAX(TIMESTAMP)`. I came up with the following. I've been able to join it in the query and it gave some performance (6 sec to 2 sec). The rare thing is that with simular queries the performance decreased when using this instead of the timestamp equation.

```
(SELECT *, rownumber = row_number() over (order by TimeStamp DESC)
FROM [Survey].CompletedSurveyStatusHistory 
WHERE CompletedSurveyId = 2) AS CompletedSurveyStatus
WHERE CompletedSurveyStatus.rownumber = 1
```

But would like to hear other alternatives or improvements if they are possible

Comment: Using local variables will usually get you a lousy plan. If this is supposed to test perf for a stored procedure, you should approach it differently. Shorter: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/ Longer: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: My first choice would be to write a stored procedure that takes the variables. For more options, read the longer article.

Comment: Some additional general advice - if you're not using data from a table, don't include it in the join (it doesn't look like any columns from `[SurveyRevisions].ResearchDetails` show up in the query, outside of the join to that table itself). If you just need to make sure that there's at least one matching row in that table, a `WHERE EXISTS` might be more efficient, and make more sense to the next person to edit the code.

Comment: @RDFozz That's a fail on my part. I created this query based on a other one and I forgot to remove it. That being said, I need to build in a check for myself to check it. Even though, I get your standpoint from the WHERE exists